# SQL Server 2008 R2: Refuses connections after some time

Tags: sql-server

First of all I would like to tell you that the program that I'm working with is already compiled and I can't look at the source code.

So, here's my problem:

The applications successfully opens about 31 connections to a specific database.
When it attempts to open 32th connection, all connections start to close, including the previous 31 connections.

To be honest, I don't know why this applications needs that many connections open to the same 2-3 tables, but after all connections are closed the application closes too.

> 17:41:38 004db680 DRIVER={SQL
> Server};SERVER=192.168.1.8:1433;UID=user;PWD=password;DATABASE=database
>
> 17:41:38 004db680 08001 0000000e [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][DBNETLIB]Invalid connection. 0x00000000 17:41:38 004db680
> 01000 0000000e [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server
> Driver][DBNETLIB]ConnectionOpen (ParseConnectParams()). 0x00000000

That's the log output from that application.

Some additional info:

- Same problem with SYN Attack protections disabled
- Database maximum connections are 30k+

Comment: If the application was written in managed code, you could try decompiling it. I've found that Telerik's [JustDecompile](http://www.telerik.com/products/decompiler.aspx) works pretty well.

Comment: Could you supply the connection string you are using please?

Comment: I think when 32th connections fails your application throws an unhandled error and it goes to shut down and it going to close all other connections at first, So your problem is in failure of 32th connection that may comes from maximum connection reaches ;).

Answer (score 1):

Run this statement on your database to see if you're exceeding maximum connections:

`SELECT @@MAX_CONNECTIONS`

Answer (score 0):

A few things come to mind

1. Run SQL Profiler before and during the app's execution.  What output do you see?  Maybe there's a deadlock occurring?
2. Has this worked previously and recently stopped working?  If so, did you apply a service pack or other fix to SQL?
3. If your app is multi-threaded, and they're doing X connections per thread, maybe try limiting the app to run on a single core rather than multiple cores.  It's a dirty hack but it might help.
4. What if you opened 32x command prompt windows and then used the osql or sqlcmd utilities to open 32 connections to SQL?  Sounds silly but if the above doesn't bear fruit at least you can see if it's merely the number of connections or if there's something else afoot.  That something else could be either

   - data related (see #1); or
   - driver related (inside the app).  Given it's using ODBC, and maybe it's old   (you don't say what Windows version, SQL version, etc is running) you could try updating MDAC  (MIcrosoft Data Access Components)?